# Outlook javascript add-in does not run when email is encrypted

Tags: encryption, outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I'm providing an add-in in Outlook on the Web, but I'm seeing unexpected behavior when I encrypt my email.

Details are described below.

■Expected behavior

The result dialog is displayed when the "displayDialogAsync" method is executed.

■Current behavior

The result dialog is not displayed even though the "displayDialogAsync" method is executed,and an email was sent.

■Steps to reproduce

1. Download the official sample. 　
   　 https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send/blob/master/outlook-add-in-on-send/Contoso%20Message%20Body%20Checker.xml/
2. Rewrite the contents of the "app.js" file to the source code of  following"index.js"
3. Run the "yarn start" command in your local environment.
4. Install the add-in with the manifest file.
5. Write an Email.
6. Click “Encrypt”.
7. Click “Send" button.

This problem always occurs.
Please tell me how to solve this problem.

I share this result on video and source code.

■video

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h3oJSZxObmOXwBw5Z1rjG92U36d9zSFz/view?usp=sharing

■source code

index.js

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT license.
 * See LICENSE in the project root for license information.
 */

var mailboxItem;

Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    mailboxItem = Office.context.mailbox.item;
}

// Entry point for Contoso Message Body Checker add-in before send is allowed.
// <param name="event">MessageSend event is automatically passed by BlockOnSend code to the function specified in the manifest.</param>
function validateBody(event) {
  Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
  "https://localhost:3000/index.html",
    {
      height: 65,
      width: 40,
      displayInIframe: true,
      asyncContext: event,
    },
      (asyncResult) => {
        asyncResult.value.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived,
        (processMessage) => {
          asyncResult.value.close()
          asyncResult.asyncContext.completed({ allowEvent: false })
        }
      )
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest posting this as an issue to the OfficeJS repo at GitHub instead.

Comment: Eugene Astafiev - Hi, Thank you for me contact. 
I understand.

Comment: This is being tracked by github issue https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/2618

Comment: Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT - thanks for your reply.
I found another problem with the same sample code. I share the video.
When I replied to the group, the dialog did not appear and the email was sent.
Is this a bug?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BwFUKO5pOpPXHoe3uM6gAzrH5zmGSXXU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry. This question has been resolved.